# How to encrypt a pdf file in Fedora 21

Tags: fedora-21

Is it possible to simply password protect a pdf file in Fedora 21? I previously used `pdftk` for this purpose but this is no longer available and surprisingly I cannot find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

[Mcpdf](https://github.com/m-click/mcpdf) is here to replace PDFtk

> Mcpdf is a drop-in replacement for PDFtk.
>
> It fixes PDFtk’s unicode issues when filling in PDF forms, and is
>   essentially a command line interface to the iText PDF library with a
>   PDFtk compatible syntax.

From the README on GitHub

Comment: Do you have a working example of how to password protect a pdf file using mcpdf and allow printing? When I try this using the comprable pdftk commands I get an "java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing "-" after output operation."

Comment: I am trying to emulate this command: "pdftk 1.pdf output 1.128.pdf owner_pw foo user_pw baz allow printing" as shown here: https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/

Comment: @JohnRock let me work on an example it will be nice if you accept this or up vote this, since its a good guidance to the SO question, but let me work on the example

Comment: `java -jar mcpdf.jar 1.pdf output 1.128.pdf owner_pw foo user_pw baz allow printing` this command should work.

Comment: Actually, I would have loved to accept this answer but unfortunately according to the following post the only supported method so far is form filling. The command you mentioned is what I tried, which does not work. https://github.com/m-click/mcpdf/issues/6

Comment: @JohnRock i see let me find another solution (if exists)

Comment: @JohnRock did you find something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74364/discussion-between-johnrock-and-ethaan).